# How to make a trigger in mysql that I update the data of a bitmap when ejecting another trigger from insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am working on a project in php where I have to do audit of the database of all the changes. I have a table where the table is stored changes of a **person table**

```
CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` text NOT NULL,
  `fnacimiento` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I have a users table

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_session` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activacion` int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `token_password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password_request` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_tipo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuarios_cedula` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The logbook is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `bitacorapersonas` (
  `idBitacora` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `accion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cedUsuario` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreUsuario` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `tipoUsuario` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `nombreNuevo` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreViejo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellidoNuevo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoViejo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexoNuevo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sexoViejo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefonoNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `telefonoViejo` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccionNuevo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `direccionViejo` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fnacimientoNuevo` date NOT NULL,
  `fnacimientoViejo` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuarioNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `correoNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `correoViejo` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In the people table and the user table I have a trigger for each one. But I am presenting the following: when I enter a person the data are divided into two rows apart instead of placing them in a single (for being the same person that I am entering)

The triggers are as follows

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Personas_AInsertar` AFTER INSERT ON `personas` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (accion,fecha,cedUsuario, nombreUsuario,tipoUsuario,cedula,nombreNuevo,apellidoNuevo,sexoNuevo,telefonoNuevo,direccionNuevo,fnacimientoNuevo) 
    VALUES ('Inserto',NOW(),@identificador,@identificador2,@identificador3,NEW.cedula,NEW.nombres,NEW.apellidos,NEW.sexo,NEW.telefono, NEW.direccion,NEW.fnacimiento)

CREATE TRIGGER `Usuarios_AInsertar` AFTER INSERT ON `usuarios` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (accion,fecha,cedUsuario, nombreUsuario,tipoUsuario, usuarioNuevo,correoNuevo) 
    VALUES ('Inserto',NOW(),@identificador,@identificador2,@identificador3,NEW.usuario,NEW.correo)
```

At the time of registering a person I am saving it as follows in the table bitacora

[image]

[image]

I thought of doing an update trigger in the bitacora so that when user data is logged and the trigger is triggered, the fill is filled with the same fields that are being entered by the person in the fields that are empty on the left side but I have no idea how to do it. If someone can help me or give me some idea how to do it I would appreciate it

Comment: A trigger can't make changes to the same table it's being triggered on.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why does entering a person create two rows? What is the relationship between those rows? Maybe you could use an `IF` statement in the trigger to do different things depending on if it's the first row or the second row.

Comment: Both are related, but I do not know how to do an insert trigger with inner join, in the user table, users_cedula (is the foreign key) that binds both tables @Barmar

Comment: What do you mean by "binds both tables"? I thought the issue is that you enter two rows into the `person` table, but you want only one row in the log table.

Comment: Exact because it is the same record of the same person and is being separated as if it were a different record

Comment: If it's the same person, why are the fields different? One is `V-44.444.444`, the other is `V-66.665.555`?

Comment: V-44,444,444; Was a test, are the last two rows that is V-66,665,555; And the one that leaves empty the cedula but that in the end shows the user and the mail of that user @Barmar

Comment: So one row is coming from `personas`, the other row is coming from `usuarios`, and you want to merge them? I thought you meant that you were creating two `personas`.

Comment: Is `usuarios_cedula` a foreign key to `personas.cedula`?

Comment: Yes, the last two are from the same person but they separate and I do not know how to merge both registers so that it comes out on the same line @Barmar and yes the foreing ktey is usuarios_cedula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `usuarios_cedula` is a foreign key to `personas.cedula`, you can do this in the second trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Usuarios_AInsertar` AFTER INSERT ON `usuarios` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE bitacorapersonas
    SET usuarioNuevo = NEW.usuario, correoNuevo = NEW.correo
    WHERE cedula = NEW.usuarios_cedula
```

This will add these two columns to the row that was inserted by the trigger on `personas`.

Comment: This trigger in the user table failed?

Comment: Sorry, got order of `WHERE` and `SET` clauses backwards.

Comment: As you had previous works,Because always the WHERE Goes last me funciono en phpmyadmin voy a probar en el sistema. gracias por responder y por la ayuda

Comment: Ok, your insert worked perfectly and now if I want to modify some data (user or mail) as I do to leave next to the modifications of personal data

Comment: Apply your code to modify but I do not understand because at the time of making a first modification to the mail does it well, then the second time I make the change in the two rows, it should show the last change, not modify all records of that user CREATE TRIGGER Usuarios_AModificar AFTER UPDATE ON usuarios FOR EACH ROW UPDATE bitacorapersonas SET usuarioNuevo = NEW.usuario, correoNuevo = NEW.correo, correoViejo=old.correo,activacionNueva = new.activacion, activacionVieja=old.activacion WHERE cedula = NEW.usuarios_cedula @barmar

Comment: My answer is for `INSERT` triggers, it assumes you're only inserting the user once, so there shouldn't be duplicates. If you also need this for `UPDATE`, you need some way to link the user and person to the log so that it knows which row to update.

Comment: Triggers might not be the best way to do this. Maybe use a stored procedure that makes the changes to both tables and then inserts a single row into the log table.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

- Define a key
- Change your `TRIGGERS` to have `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

And take care that this is running in a transaction.

By having both check on the key, the order of the actions does not have to be guaranteed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Personas_AInsertar` AFTER INSERT ON `personas` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (accion,fecha,cedUsuario, nombreUsuario,tipoUsuario,cedula,nombreNuevo,apellidoNuevo,sexoNuevo,telefonoNuevo,direccionNuevo,fnacimientoNuevo) 
    VALUES ('Inserto',NOW(),@identificador,@identificador2,@identificador3,NEW.cedula,NEW.nombres,NEW.apellidos,NEW.sexo,NEW.telefono, NEW.direccion,NEW.fnacimiento) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE....

CREATE TRIGGER `Usuarios_AInsertar` AFTER INSERT ON `usuarios` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (accion,fecha,cedUsuario, nombreUsuario,tipoUsuario, usuarioNuevo,correoNuevo) 
    VALUES ('Inserto',NOW(),@identificador,@identificador2,@identificador3,NEW.usuario,NEW.correo) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ....
```

If you know that the order of execution is fixed, you can make your live easier by running an `INSERT` in the first trigger and an `UPDATE` in the second trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Personas_AInsertar` AFTER INSERT ON `personas` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO bitacorapersonas (accion,fecha,cedUsuario, nombreUsuario,tipoUsuario,cedula,nombreNuevo,apellidoNuevo,sexoNuevo,telefonoNuevo,direccionNuevo,fnacimientoNuevo) 
    VALUES ('Inserto',NOW(),@identificador,@identificador2,@identificador3,NEW.cedula,NEW.nombres,NEW.apellidos,NEW.sexo,NEW.telefono, NEW.direccion,NEW.fnacimiento) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE....

CREATE TRIGGER `Usuarios_AInsertar` AFTER INSERT ON `usuarios` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE bitacorapersonas
    SET ....
```

About security of the actual keeping of a log like this:
If you do not protect your log and your data with a checksum of some kind, the data can still be altered in the log in such a way that you can not determine reality. By adding a checksum methodology, you have easier and more portable proof of tampering with the data.